# .animate() not triggering if page is not newly opened or is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the questions for the first time, you can see the animation for showing the answers. But when I closed it and open it again, it will just default to slidedown and my animation is not working anymore.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>One Month jQuery</title>
            <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
            <div class="panel">
                <div id="q1" class="question">1. What is jQuery?
                    <img id="arrow1-down" class="arrow down" src="assets/arrow-down.svg">
                    <img id="arrow1-up" class="arrow up collapse" src="assets/arrow-up.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="a1" class="answer collapse">
                    jQuery is a JavaScript framework, which purpose is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website. You could also describe jQuery as an abstraction layer, since it takes a lot of the functionality that you would have to write many lines of JavaScript to accomplish and wraps it into functions that you can call with a single line of code.
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="panel">
                <div id="q2" class="question">2. Do I need to know JavaScript to use jQuery?
                    <img id="arrow2-down" class="arrow down" src="assets/arrow-down.svg">
                    <img id="arrow2-up" class="arrow up collapse" src="assets/arrow-up.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="a2" class="answer collapse">
                    No, you don't need to know JavaScript to use jQuery. In fact, jQuery tries to simplify a lot of the complicated things with JavaScript, like AJAX calls and DOM manipulation, so that you may do these things without knowing JavaScript.
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="panel">
                <div id="q3" class="question">3. Does jQuery replace JavsScript?
                    <img id="arrow3-down" class="arrow down" src="assets/arrow-down.svg">
                    <img id="arrow3-up" class="arrow up collapse" src="assets/arrow-up.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="a3" class="answer collapse">
                    jQuery does NOT replace JavaScript, and while it does offer some syntactical shortcuts, the code you write when you use jQuery is still JavaScript code.
                </div>
            <br>
            <div class="panel">
                <div id="q4" class="question">4. Can I start learning jQuery without ever learning HTML & CSS?
                    <img id="arrow3-down" class="arrow down" src="assets/arrow-down.svg">
                    <img id="arrow3-up" class="arrow up collapse" src="assets/arrow-up.svg">
                </div>
                <div id="a4" class="answer collapse">
                    <img src="assets/no.gif" alt="No">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    color: #3b3b3b;
    margin: 50px 150px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.panel {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f6;
}

.question {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f7f7f6;
}

.question:hover {
    color: #149ed8;
}

.arrow {
    width: 17px;
    height: 11px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.answer {
    padding: 30px 10px;
    opacity: 0.08;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 4;
    background: #CAE1FF;
}

.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".question").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow").animate({
            "opacity": "1",
            "line-height": "20",
            "padding": "10px"
        });
        $(this).children().toggleClass("collapse");
    });
});
```

Comment: we cant do anything without the html..

Comment: Try switching to `$(".question").on('click', function(){});`

Comment: @Anoop Joshi I put the full project file dropbox link. You can download it to see the .html file

Comment: @Twisty I'm sorry but what should I switch?

Comment: Forget that. The issue here I think is that you set values in your animation, and then when you collapse, you don't revert the values back to their originals. Hence the second time you expand, it does not have the same effect.

Comment: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cz2hyx2p/1/

Comment: Yup that's exactly the problem. You know how to keep the animation trigger even after collapsing?

Comment: @JeramaeBohol http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/khn1fjbn/1/ ?

Comment: @Arun P Johny I don't understand the code but this works the way I wanted I just changed the line-height from 4px to 40px. I believe you wanted 40px instead of 4px also right?

Comment: @JeramaeBohol yes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag to know when the answer is open or closed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question").click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow").animate({
            "opacity": "1",
            "line-height": "20",
            "padding": "10px"
        });
       //$(this).children().toggleClass("collapse");
        var open = ($(this).next().css("display") == "block");
        if(open){
            $(this).next().css({
                "opacity": "0.08",
                "line-height": "4",
                "padding": "30px 10px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/72kqvzy9/

Comment: Watch it in FireBug, if you click to collapse before the expand animation completes, the CSS is not returned. Not sure how often people will click it that rapidly, so not sure if it's worth finding a work around.

Comment: After I made my comment, it did occur to me that you could make another flag, that is true when the animation is running, and then use a callback function to set it to false when it's complete. Then you can just return if that is true right away in your `click()`, basically disabling the click when the animation is still active.